# The difference between 'setLevel' of a logger and 'setLevel' of a handler connected to the logger

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to grasp the difference between the impact of `logger.setLevel` and the impact of `handler.setLevel`, where the `logger` and the `handler` are created as follows:

```
import logging

def getLogger(name, loggerLevel, handlerLevel):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(handlerLevel)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(loggerLevel)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

Note that the `handler` is connected to the `logger`.

Here is what the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) says about `setLevel`:

> Sets the threshold for this logger to `level`. Logging messages which are less severe than `level` will be ignored; logging messages which have severity `level` or higher will be emitted by whichever handler or handlers service this logger, unless a handler’s `level` has been set to a higher severity level than `level`.

I didn't quite fully understand this, so I implemented the following script to test all possible combinations:

```
for loggerLevel in ['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR']:
    for handlerLevel in ['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR']:
        name = loggerLevel + '_' + handlerLevel
        print('{}:'.format(name))
        logger = getLogger(name,eval('logging.'+loggerLevel),eval('logging.'+handlerLevel))
        logger.debug  ('    debug  ')
        logger.info   ('    info   ')
        logger.warning('    warning')
        logger.error  ('    error  ')
```

And the output (see below) proves one thing - the higher level out of the two is the one to determine the course of action, **regardless** of which entity was set to that level.

So my question is - why do we need more than one level to begin with?

```
DEBUG_DEBUG:
    debug
    info
    warning
    error
DEBUG_INFO:
    info
    warning
    error
DEBUG_WARNING:
    warning
    error
DEBUG_ERROR:
    error
INFO_DEBUG:
    info
    warning
    error
INFO_INFO:
    info
    warning
    error
INFO_WARNING:
    warning
    error
INFO_ERROR:
    error
WARNING_DEBUG:
    warning
    error
WARNING_INFO:
    warning
    error
WARNING_WARNING:
    warning
    error
WARNING_ERROR:
    error
ERROR_DEBUG:
    error
ERROR_INFO:
    error
ERROR_WARNING:
    error
ERROR_ERROR:
    error
```

Answer (score 4):

You can attach more than one *handler* to a logger, and logger levels matter when *propagating* messages in a hierarchy.

Using multiple handlers lets you direct different severity levels to different outputs. You can put `WARNING` messages to the console, `INFO` and better go to the system log, and `DEBUG` messages go to an application-specific log file. This is what setting the log level on a handler is for, to configure what messages each handler will process, independently.

Logger levels matter in a hierarchy; all loggers are children of the root logger, and you can create further levels by using `.` dots in the name. You can then pick and choose what loggers produce what levels of output; setting a more strict log level means the logger will not process a message (including not handing it to the parent logger).

For example, many third-party libraries will produce log output at various levels. So, for a specific application, it could be quite helpful to see the `ERROR` level messages produced by the `urllib3` library, but for SQLAlchemy you only want to see `WARNING` messages. You just configure the levels for these library loggers with a `getLogger(name_of_library)` call to stop them propagating lower level messages to the root logger, where the handlers typically live.

Comment: OK, but in that case, what's the point in setting the logging-level of the logger itself? Shouldn't it be enough to set the logging level of each handler?

Comment: @goodvibration: Sure, unless you have a collection of different loggers. Like those in third-party libraries, or in your own larger application.

Comment: @goodvibration: in a small script or application, sure, there is little point. But the library can handle far more complex use cases.